# What is the difference between entity and relationship

Tags: rdbms

I am new to the RDBMS.

I am Learning ER model in RDBMS.
In ER model, the entity is an real world object and it has an attributes.
The relationship is an mapping between entity set.
The relationship also have a the attributes.
Please explain the difference between entity and relationship.

Comment: You just described the difference, then asked what it is?

Comment: You told difference and asking same. Could you please point exactly what you want to know ??? As of now , we are not sure what is question ?

Comment: The answer is in the description of your question itself.

Comment: Please explain is there any other difference between these two other than the description in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have the definition differences available. But I assume you still do not understand the differences. Here is a very simplified example of two entities and the relationship that may exist between them:

A `Bank` and a `Person` are each an entity. The relationship that exists between a `Bank` and a `Person` is that a `Person` is a `Customer` to a `Bank`. Therefore `Customer` is the relationship. An attribute for a `Person` for example would be `Date_of_Birth`. An attribute for a `Bank` would be `Bank_Name` . An attribute for a `Customer` would be `Customer_Bank_Acc_Number`.

---

**Update:**
For those that like to pick at details here is a better relationship example:

A `Person` can have a relationship with a `Bank` of either being a `Debtor` or `Creditor`.

---

**Update**

There is also what is called an [`Associative Entity`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28905166/difference-between-associative-entity-and-associative-relationship-attribute). Click the link for details on how that is different to an `Associative Relationship`.

I hope this makes sense. Cheers

Comment: I understand this. Is there any other differences between entity and relationship.

Comment: @sureshkumar oh okay. What you mentioned in your post is the main difference really. Nothing more to it.

Comment: @sureshkumar all good. Please see my last update, in case that is what you were actually looking for.